# applications of derivatives in economics

Tags: derivatives

if given the cost function of producing $x$ products as $C(x)=x^3-3x^2-80x+500 $ and each product is sold at $2800$ dollars,what weekly production rate will maximize the profit and what is the largest possible profit per week?
here is what i did
$R(x)= 2880x$ and $P(x)= R(x)-C(x)$
so $P(x)= -x^3+3x^2+2880x-500$
$P'(x)=-3x^2+6x+2880$
the factors are $32$ and $-30$ so $x$ has zero at $32$ and $-30$
from here,how do I get the maximum point?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i looked for the profit function by taking 2800x-x^3-3x^2-80x+500 and calculated P'(x) to get the max and min points which were-30 and 32.From this I don't know what to do next

Comment: You should include your attempts into the body of your question.

Comment: note: $\pi=TR-TC \Rightarrow \pi'=MR-MC=0$ and $TR=PQ=2800x$.

Answer (score 1):

Double differentiate the profit function and check the sign at candidate point to find maxima. We have
$$P''(x)=-6x+6$$
Observe that $P''(32)<0$. Hence, $32$ is the required point of maxima. In other words, the optimum number of products to maximise profit is $32$. Hence the required production rate is $32$ products per week.

Comment: i understand, thank you

Comment: @Beatricechakali, upvote and accept this answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute the values you got in $P(x)$.

$P'(x)=0$ at a maximum or minimum of point, so substitute both $32$ and $-30$ and the higher is the maximum.

Also note that there can't be $-30$ products!

Another method is to check the double derivative, the value that $P''(x)<0$ on, is the maximum (because the concavity is downward)